# Why does my ParsePush not sending from an Android client when attaching a URI?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have the following notification code working:

```
private void sendNotification(ParseUser user) {
  ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
  ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
  query.whereEqualTo("user", user);
  push.setQuery(query);
  push.setMessage("Notification!");
  push.sendInBackground();
}
```

However, when I try to attach a URI to the notification, this does not send (the receiver does not get it and there is no entry in the Push console), but no errors are logged, or thrown when I debug it.

```
private void sendNotification(ParseUser user, String uri) {
  ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
  ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
  query.whereEqualTo("user", user);
  push.setQuery(query);
  JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
  try {
    data.put("alert", "Notification!");
    data.put("uri", uri);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.w("sendNotification", "sendNotification failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  push.setData(data);
  push.sendInBackground();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently according to this post, you can't send notifications with a URI when using Client push as a security precaution, which is understandable, but it would be nice if it raised an error to let you know.

http://blog.parse.com/2014/09/